# Java : Could not load or find main class TrudiHw

Tags: java, textpad

I keep getting this error when trying to run my basic java code. It compiles with no errors at all but for some reason the program wont actually run. I am using textpad. Here is my code.

```
/*
*TrudiHw.java
*Trudi Farrell
*19/10/15
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TrudiHw{
    public static void main (String args[]){
    int input;
    int answer;

    Scanner keyboard;

    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many students are attendting the trip?");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    answer = input/5;

    System.out.println("The amount of cars you will need is " +answer);

    }
}
```

Comment: What command did you use to compile it?

Comment: I just click ctrl + 1 and it compiles

Comment: How do you execute it? And what is the error when it fails?

Comment: in textpad you use Ctrl + 2 to run the java application but i get the message in the CMD saying "Error: could not find or load main class TrudiHw"